# python - How to remove punctuation in between words

Tags: python

I use the code to strip a line of text from punctuation:

```
line = line.rstrip("\n")
line = line.translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

The problem is that words like `doesn't` turn to `doesnt` so now I want to remove the punctuation only between words but can't seem to figure out a way to do so. How
should I go about this?

Edit: I thought about using the `strip()` function but that will only take effect on the right and left trailing of the whole sentence.

For example:

```
Isn't ., stackoverflow the - best ?
```

Should become:

```
Isn't stackoverflow the best
```

Instead of the current output:

```
Isnt stackoverflow the best
```

Comment: I think you need to explain your exact requirements more formally, with some concrete "before and after" examples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you consider words as groups of characters separated by spaces:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> line = "Isn't ., stackoverflow the - best ?"
>>> ' '.join(word.strip(punctuation) for word in line.split() 
             if word.strip(punctuation))
"Isn't stackoverflow the best"
```

or

```
>>> line = "Isn't ., stackoverflow the - best ?"
>>> ' '.join(filter(None, (word.strip(punctuation) for word in line.split())))
"Isn't stackoverflow the best"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
line = line.translate(None, string.punctuation.replace('\'', ''))
```

Is this what u want?